# How to set multiple actions in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
$('#find').click(function() {...
```

I need to also add to that event that if they press the enter key it will also execute.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
if ( ($('#find').click()) || (code == 13)) {
```

But obviously it does not work. How can I merge both ways into one. Pressing enter should work only when done in the input with id="code". The click event is for another input type button with id="find". I want to merge both that, if the user presses enter while typing the code or clicking the button to send the code, both ways work the same way.

Comment: Just set `#find` as `type="submit"` and it will work by Enter automaticly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
function myHandler(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); //whatever you need to do here
}
$('#find').click(myHandler); 
$('#find').keypress(function(){
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
   if(code == 13) myHandler();
);
```

or maybe use keyup, you should read the docs on that: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1):

Use `on()`:

```
$('#find').on('click keypress', function(e){
    if (e.type == 'click' || e.which == '13') {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ch3vJ/1/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Glad to have been of help. =)

Answer (score 0):

An extension on this is:

```
$('#find').on('click',function(event,params) {

  // your click code here    

}).on('keypress'),function(event) {

  // if you have 13, then send the click evnet
  // this way lets you do other things by passing the params
  // object, if you wish

  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(13 == code) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    return false;
  }

  // other code that executes if code != 13

});
```